# How to use dictionary in oop to store data

Tags: python, dictionary, oop

i want to ask you i want to store all informations in dictionary for this code but i can't i know that something i did wrong.I like to store informations from Customers if issue take a hourly , monthly or daily it is on BikeRental request bikes what i tried by far is any way?

```
class Customers:
    def __init__(self,stock,unique_number,family_rent,salary):
        self.issue_bill = {}
        self.request_bikes = []
        self.unique_number = unique_number
        self.family_rent = family_rent
        self.stock = stock
        self.salary = salary
    def available_bikes(self):
        print("Unique number is: " , self.unique_number)
        print("Stock available: " , self.stock)
        print("Requested bikes at the moment are:", str(self.request_bikes)[1:-1])
    
    def bike_hourly_basics(self,bike):
        if self.stock < bike:
            print("Not enough bikes on stock!")
        else:
            print("You can rent this bike for 10euro on hourly!")
            self.stock = self.stock - bike
            

            
            
         
    def bike_daily_basics(self,bike):
        if self.stock < bike:
            print("Not enough bikes on stock!")
        elif bike == 0:
            print("Enter positive integer , not zero")
        else:
            print("You can rent this bike for 30euro on daily!")
            self.stock = self.stock - bike

    
    def bike_weekly_basics(self,bike):
        if self.stock < bike:
            print("Not enough bikes on stock!")
        elif bike == 0:
            print("Enter positive integer , not zero")
        else:
            print("You can rent this bike for 60euro on weekly!")
            self.stock = self.stock - bike
    
    def family_rent(self):
        if self.family_rent < 3:
            print("Not enough people for the discount")
        else:
            print("Good job , the discount of 3 or more people is: " , self.salary - value )
        
class BikeRental:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_accounts = {}
    
    def request_bikes(self,stock,unique_number,family_rent,salary):
        customer = Customers(stock,unique_number,family_rent,salary)
        self.all_accounts[stock,unique_number] = customer 
        for key,value in self.all_accounts.items():
            print(key)

customer = Customers(5 , 40607 , 4 , 5000)
bike = BikeRental()
bike.request_bikes(3,50607 , 5 , 6000)
```

Comment: I don't get a problem - the program works, what do you expect from it?

Comment: i want in BikeRental on request bikes function to request every bike if i reach function from Customers for example i call the function bike hourly basics and it request it this person has issue a rent for one hour did u undestand now better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanted to store all information in a dictionary in request_bikes function then you can use something like below

```
def request_bikes(self, stock, unique_number, family_rent, salary):
    customer = Customers(stock, unique_number, family_rent, salary)
    #self.all_accounts[stock, unique_number] = customer
    self.all_accounts['stock']= customer.stock
    self.all_accounts['unique_number'] = customer.unique_number
    self.all_accounts['family_rent'] = customer.family_rent
    self.all_accounts['salary'] = customer.salary
    return self.all_accounts
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you a lot for these you really helped me but do you know how should i did this: When someone rents bike then you should keep it as dictionary with tuples {unique_number: (number of bikes, type or rent hourly, weekly or monthly)} and customer should get unique number